# Cobertura, suppress lines never should come

Tags: java, code-coverage, cobertura

I am using cobertura first time. Everything works fine but what I wonder is,
there are lines in my code, which should never be called like:

```
try {
    em.persist();
}catch(Exception) {
    logger.error("can not create");
}
```

I am doing all controls until persist line, when my code works fine, error line never be reached and now it is so. Because of it I never have %100 line coverage.

Should I somehow suppress it?

Thanks, Bilal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you can exclude entire classes from your Cobertura coverage reports, you cannot exclude specific lines or methods.

You should accept that 100% coverage is impossible to achieve in real-life projects, since there will always be unreachable code or code that can only be reached by simulating a complex combination of conditions.

As other answers suggest, you can try and increase the unit test coverage by mocking/stubbing an `EntityManager` to throw an exception on `persist`. But this is pretty much as far as you can go.

Answer (score 0):

write an unit test which covers the exception throwing case.

Comment: this is impossible, becuase i am doing all controlls in my dao.
when code reaches until this code, will evertything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say an exception occuring from the "persist" method can't happen.  What happens if the db connection parameters are wrong, or someone mucked with the mapping annotations and messed up a column name?  That would all trigger an exception.  Catching and swallowing this can cause your unit test to succeed when it should fail on the exception.